# Single package deployment in SSIS2012

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS 2012 solution which has 50 Packages. In the latest project deployment model we have to deploy the entire project even if there is any change in one single package. Is there a way of deploying that one single package and not the entire solution(ispac)?

Answer (score 0):

No.

[Incremental package deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522534.aspx#IncrementalDeployment) for SSISDB is not an option until you get to SQL Server 2016